# MySQL find any records between date range

Tags: mysql

I'm building simple reservation form. Let's say, I want to book a car from 2015-07-12 to 2015-07-21.

In database we have record, that there is allready reserved car (car_id 18) from 2015-07-15 to 2015-07-20.

Here is my query, to check if there is reserved car:

```
SELECT * FROM `reservation` WHERE `reservation_from` <= '2015-07-12' AND `reservation_to` <= '2015-07-21' AND `car_id` = 18
```

After query, I got record, that there is already reserved car. All is good.

And now, let's say, I want to reserve car from 2015-07-09 to 2015-07-19.

This time, I got empty result. But there is record, that car is reserved from 2015-07-15 to 2015-07-20!

I have played with `<=` `>=` operators, and no luck.

Yes, both columns are in date format.

What I'm missing? How to get this record, that there is allready booked car within selected date range?

And yes, MySQL is not my strongest side.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MySql between clause with dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964740/using-mysql-between-clause-with-dates)

Comment: Seems like there's information missing here

Comment: so if the problem is to save a car during a predetermined period, do you have a code example from which we can work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want *any* overlap, not a complete overlap.  So the logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `reservation`
WHERE `reservation_from` <= '2015-07-21' AND
      `reservation_to` >= '2015-07-12' AND 
      `car_id` = 18;
```

That is, there is no car available if a reservation starts before the period ends and ends after the period starts.

Comment: @Sadikhasan . . . There was a missing `AND` on the first clause.

Comment: Here is quick fiddle [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a67a94/8), can't get to work your suggestion

Comment: Ahhhhhh, now understood. Why sometimes head is not working?!!! Thank You all for answers!

Comment: '2015-07-21' BETWEEN x AND y seems nice too.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I don't advise people on this forum to use `between` with dates.  Aaron Bertrand has a blog on this (although written for SQL Server, mostly applicable to other databases):  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.  The basic problem is you don't know, by looking at a column, whether or not there is a time component, and the time component throws things off.

Comment: All well and good - except `SELECT '2015-01-01' >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'` = 0

Comment: @Strawberry . . . (1) Wow, that is really strange.  Do you know what that occurs?  (2) In this case, I think the dates are dates so it works.  And (3) `between` isn't appropriate for this logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query :

```
  SELECT *
  FROM `reservation`
  WHERE
 `reservation_from` <= '2015-07-21' AND 
 `reservation_to` >= '2015-07-12' AND 
 `car_id` = 18;
```

Comment: i was writting the answer and in the meantime he writes the same answer